# Netbeans Adding Derby Driver

Tags: jdbc, netbeans, driver, derby

Netbeans --> Window --> Services -->  Databases --> Drivers

I've mistakenly deleted all files from this folder. 
I succeed to add Java DB Embeded driver.
But I'm not able to add Network driver & others as I don't know their class name.

Before Deleting It was looking like this,
[What should be the Driver Name Here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCKMR.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Netbeans (8.2 - but I see no reason why other versions would be different):

Driver files:

```
path\to\jdk\db\lib\derbyclient.jar
path\to\jdk\db\lib\derby.jar
```

Driver Class

```
org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Comment: I tried to accept answer, but it was prompting that I can accept the answer after 5 minutes.